# On demand upload server

Tags: ftp, upload

I'm looking for a simple application which will do something like

```
Allow user to sign up for an ftp account -> ask admin for approval -> create ftp account for that user
```

now it doesn't have to be FTP, in fact I would be happy with a web based tool which supported upload via some sort of java applet or something similar.  I don't care about what platform it runs on, although if we could avoid PHP that would be cool.  Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldnt this be moved to SF?

Comment: Oh, maybe it should be.

Comment: This isn't complete enough to be an answer, but most ftp servers just use the actual system users as ftp logins and their home directories as upload/download space. You could just have the web form email you when someone signs up and then have a shell script to add the user, set their password, and do any other configuration needed to get the desired result. Edit: I'm talking about Linux here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What platform? Without this, I am just giving some general advice.

This is easy to achieve and I have just made something similar for my company but it depends on a number of things and will usually require a bit of scripting.

The easiest way is to find a FTP server that supports a database for user membership, then all you need to do is create a small website in the language of your choice and simply take username and password along with anything else you want. You can then set that script to send you a email with all the details or simply have it display on another (admin) webpage, and a delete or confirm button.

When you press delete, it deletes the entry (of course!) and when you click confirm, it can enter the details in to the database of the FTP server.

You can also use a FTP server that has membership in any form (such as XML files or windows / unix accounts) but having one that has a database backend is so much simpler.

Also, You could have all users in one database, if they are confirmed or not, but I said the above just for simplicity as you probably do not want thousands of unconfirmed / disabled ftp users.

Comment: I don't care what platform.  I was hoping OpenBSD but I really just don't care.  I'll throw it on a VM and that will be that.  I could certainly make one but that is a lot of work.  Let's go shopping!

Comment: I'd advise archiving the deleted entry so you can simply automatically deny duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

if its openBSD you might look at hosting a file FTP site using [Freenas](http://freenas.org). Freenas can be used as a webserver now, so you could do it.